# Combinatorial proof of the following $p_k(n)=q_k\bigg(n+\begin{pmatrix}k\\2\end{pmatrix}\bigg)$

Tags: combinatorics

Let $q_k(n)$ denote the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ distinct parts. Give a combinatorial proof of the equality
$$p_k(n)=q_k\bigg(n+\begin{pmatrix}k\\2\end{pmatrix}\bigg).$$
With $p_k(n)$ is the number of partitions of $n$ into $k$ parts.

I can see this is true from examples, I'm unsure how to start a proof, if anyone can point me in the right direction it would be appreciated. 
Writing out examples makes it seem like adding $k$ to one part of each of the partitions of $p_k(n)$, gives a partition of $q_k(n)$.

Answer (score 0):

You could draw a Ferrers diagram.

But as a special case: if $(a_1,a_2,a_3)$ is a partition of $n$
into three distinct parts (so $a_1>a_2>a_3>0$) then $(a_1-2,a_2-1,a_3)$
is a partition of $n-3$ into three (not necessarily distinct) parts, etc.

Comment: Note that ${k\choose2}=0+1+\cdots+(k-1)$, so the equality to prove is $p_k(n)=q_k\bigg(n+(0+1+\cdots+(k-1))\bigg).$